# How to calculate the field distribution due to a current radiating in one direction?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, potential, maxwell-equations, greens-functions

Given a surface current distribution, $\textbf{J}(r)$, we can calculate the magnetic potential in the Lorenz gauge using
$$
\textbf{A}(\textbf{r})=-μ_{0} ∬g(\textbf{r},\textbf{r}')\textbf{J}(\textbf{r}')dA'
$$
where
$$
g(\textbf{r},\textbf{r}')=-\frac{e^{ik_{0}|r-r'|}}{4π|r-r'|}
$$
is the Green’s function (I’m using an $e^{-iωt}$ temporal dependence throughout). The magnetic field can then be calculated using
$$
\textbf{H}(\textbf{r})=\frac{1}{\mu_{0}}∇×\textbf{A}(\textbf{r})
$$
Doing this for a perfectly conducting infinite planar sheet located at $x=0$ supporting a uniform surface current $J$ in the $z$ direction leads to a magnetic field
$$
\textbf{H}(\textbf{r})=\frac{sign(x)J}{2}e^{ik_{0}|x|}y
$$
If we impose that the whole region x<0 is occupied by a conductor, then, by observation, the magnetic field is
$$
H(r)=Je^{ik_{0}x}
$$
in $x>0$ and vanishing in $x<0$. My question is whether there is a way of deriving this latter magnetic field using an equation of the type
$$
\textbf{A}(\textbf{r})=-μ_{0} ∬g(\textbf{r},\textbf{r}')\textbf{J}(\textbf{r}')dA'
$$
i.e. using the Green’s function. Essentially I want to impose that the radiation due to the current locally propagates only in one direction (in reality I don’t have an infinite sheet so I can’t work out the answer just by observation).

Comment: > *"then, by observation, the magnetic field is...vanishing in $x<0$."* -- Can you elaborate? Do you mean observation in real world? There is no infinite conductive half-spaces in real world...

Comment: I fail to see how a harmonic current density tangential to and oriented along an infinite conducting surface would create any field at all... Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of an infinite perfectly conducting plane, you can use the image theorem.

That is, since there is a perfectly conductive half space for $x<0$, the current density $\mathbf{J}(x',y',z')$ in the other half space $x\geq 0$ can be modified to include an image current. The x-component becomes of this modified current density becomes $J_x(x',y',z') + J_x(-x', y',z') $ and the tranverse component becomes $\mathbf{J}_T(x',y',z') - \mathbf{J}_T(-x',y',z')$. If you're using a dyadic Green's function you can instead adjust the respective components of the Green's function.

You can then set the fields to zero for $x<0$.